# Access basket from view called with unit test in Django Oscar

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-oscar

How do I attach a Django Oscar basket that has been created in a unit test to the `request` object?

```py
# views.py

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class BasketAPIAddView(LoginRequiredMixin, APIView):
    """
    Update basket via REST API.
    """
    def delete(self, request, format=None):
        #
        # cannot access `request.basket` here
        #
        return Response({})
```

```py
# tests.py

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse
from oscar.test.factories import create_basket
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

User = get_user_model()

class BasketAPITests(APITestCase):
    """
    Basket view test cases.
    """
    def test_remove_basket_line(self):
        basket = create_basket()
        basket.owner = User.objects.create_user('user', password='pass')
        basket.save()

        self.client.login(username='user', password='password')
        self.client.delete(reverse('delete-basket'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
from oscar.test.factories import create_basket


User = get_user_model()

class BasketAPITests(APITestCase):

    def test_remove_basket_line(self):
        """Check the method BasketAPIAddView.delete works as should."""

        # Create the request, note the  .delete which is the operation (BasketAPIAddView.delete)
        request = APIRequestFactory().delete(reverse('<your url name>'))

        # Create the basket
        basket = create_basket()
        basket.owner = User.objects.create_user('user', password='pass')
        basket.save()

        # Attach the basket to the request obj
        request.basket =  create_basket()

        # Call the endpoint, with the proper request obj
        response = BasketAPIAddView.as_view()(request)

        # Some verifications
        ...
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        ...
```

The key is to use a request factory and have the object at your will (adding what you need).

For more details you can take a look to https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/

Answer (score 0):

For normal requests `oscar.apps.basket.middleware.BasketMiddleware` adds the basket to the request, so it is possible you need to check the `settings.MIDDLEWARE` that your test project is using, or that the client provided by `APITestCase` is running middleware.

If you're developing an API you might also want to look at the way [django-oscar-api](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-api) handles session management and middleware.